# Generate unique string ID with nanoid

Tags: javascript, nanoid

I'm using [nanoid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nanoid) to generate a unique string ID. I have some questions.

**1-**  When I limit size is the outcome unique?

```
const nanoid = nanoid(6)
```

**2-** I do not want some letters such as **(- and _ )** in the result. How can I do that and dose the outcome is unique?

**3-**  I know that I can use `customAlphabet` to generate keys. dose the result of `customAlphabet` unique?

```
import { customAlphabet } from 'nanoid'
const nanoid = customAlphabet('1234567890abcdef', 10)
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that nanoid guarantees uniqueness of the IDs it creates. Like [UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier), it's probabilistic, based on random number generation. The chance of a collision depends on the size of the alphabet and the length of the ID string - that's why they provide an [ID collision probability calculator.](https://zelark.github.io/nano-id-cc/)